# Manipulate a image just by a click

Tags: php, gd

I would like to know whether it is possible to convert the following [base image](http://mockup.zxq.net/simplicity-frame.png) to [updated image](http://mockup.zxq.net/habitat-driftwood.png) using PHP GD library?

Comment: @tjmoore1993 Both 403 for me as well.

Comment: @tjmoore1993: strange. Both lead me there : http://hosting.zymic.com/403/

Comment: Base image:http://mockup.zxq.net/simplicity-frame.png and Updated image:http://mockup.zxq.net/habitat-driftwood.png

Comment: @pranav_kavi: the message I get : 403 Forbidden!

The address you have entered is not open to the public,
(This may be caused by not having a index.html file in your root directory).

Answer (score 1):

Anything is possible. You can reimplement every algorithm in Adobe Photoshop in PHP if you really wanted to, reading and writing one pixel at a time to/from the image. It's just a matter of how many days/weeks/months/years you want to spend reinventing the wheel instead of finding an appropriate tool/library.

So can you turn some kind of drop shadow thing into some kind of brick thing? Yes. Can you do it automatically in one line of code? No, there's no GD function that knows that's what you want to happen.

Comment: As I am not much of a designer, what can you call this image manipulation exactly? That may help me in finding the appropriate tool/library.

Comment: I don't even understand what you want it to do. Find edges and somehow decide which of them should be turned into brick walls of a height completely unrelated to the source image?